# How to remove x axis gaps in excel graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table that contains dates and corresponding values. When I create a scatterplot, there are large gaps on both ends of the x-axis. The earliest date is 11/18/2013 and the latest date is 7/28/2019, yet the x-axis of the graph extends the graph from 2010 to 2020. How would I be able to change this?

Here is a picture for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the X-axis label and right-click on it
2. Choose "Format Axis" from the drop-down menu
3. Adjust the bounds of the axis (remember that dates are numbers in Excel)